# GCM ReconnectManager does not reconnect automatically if 3G is switched on after a long time

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

**Problem**

1. 3G is switched on, I do GCM registration and get GCM push notifications in my android app.
2. I switch off 3G, wait for around 90 minutes.
3. Switch on 3G again. This time I receive the notification after a long delay (in this example, it is 5 minutes).

Android version: 5.1.1
Device: Nexus 6
Google Play Services installed on the app: version 9.4.52

**My analysis**

I entered *#*#426#*#* on dial pad to open Google Play Services. In Step 2, when 3G is switched off, "Reconnect Manager" schedules an alarm to reconnect to GCM (mtalk.google.com:5228) after x seconds (where x is very small and it varies, say 3 secs). When re-connection attempt fails after x seconds, it schedules another alarm at 2x seconds and it goes on till it is successful in connecting to GCM.

**In step 3, when 3G is switched on again, ideally "Reconnect Manager" should have tried contacting GCM. But, it does not which is the root cause of the issue. I think this is a bug.** It waits till the alarm for re-connection is triggered. The following event gets logged in "EVENTS":
Network even while disconnected / **throttling** 0 38

If I do the following after switching on 3G in Step 3, then "Reconnect Manager" tries to contact GCM immediately:

1. Connect to a WiFi
2. Enable and disable Airplane mode

Status as shown in Google Play Services (*#*#426#*#*) after Step3

[image: Status as shown in Google Play Services (*#*#426#*#*) after Step3]

Events as shown in Google Play Services (*#*#426#*#*) after Step3

[image: Events as shown in Google Play Services (*#*#426#*#*) after Step3]

Can anyone confirm if this is a bug or expected behavior? I thought of asking it here as https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/support says that google engineers monitor questions with tag: google-cloud-messaging

Comment: Since, I have not received any reply yet, I have submitted this issue to google directly now using https://support.google.com/code/contact/gcm_dev_support

This issue is faced by one of our customers. So, it's really critical.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with [Exponential Back-off](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff)

> Exponential backoff is an algorithm that retries requests to the server based on certain status codes in the server response. The retries exponentially increase the waiting time up to a certain threshold. The idea is that if the server is down temporarily, it is not overwhelmed with requests hitting at the same time when it comes back up.

So, I believe its the intended behavior if there's a long duration of the service being down (in your scenario, about 5 mins)

Comment: But, if there is a network change i.e 3G is turned on, I think it should immediately try to contact server. They do immediately retry if we are connected to a Wifi OR enable and disable airplane mode.